# Does database normalization belong here?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, off-topic, burninate-request

As of today, we have four questions in the [normalization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normalization)-tag. One of these has already been closed, and the other three don't exactly look 100% on-topic to me as they don't include any SQL code but instead ask about the database schema.

Do these questions belong here or should we redirect all [normalization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normalization) questions to [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com)?

The way I see it is that these questions are off-topic and that the tag should [burn burn burn](http://www.youtuberepeater.com/watch?v=mIBTg7q9oNc&s=47&e=63).

Comment: I don't have enough personal experience to determine this myself, but I can still close any questions as needed.  If you or someone feels confident about this, those questions can be retagged.

Comment: Update: they're all off-topic, and I've closed them.  I'll review the database tags further to see if there are similar questions.

Comment: @Jamal is [this older question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/149/28725) (which is the reason that I posted my now-closed question here as opposed to elsewhere) now out of date?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: Basically, there must already be code to review.  The other questions I've closed had no code.  I'm not sure about the question in that Meta post because I cannot tell if that is code or not.

Comment: More questions under [database-design] have been closed, but not all of them.  I'd recommend having the wiki edited to mention that code must be provided, otherwise the question belongs on DBA.SE.

Comment: In [January 2011](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/149/9357), the general sentiment was that database design reviews were on-topic for Code Review. However, considering that DBA.SE [launched](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1) around the same time, the issue is worth revisiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[normalization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normalization) has now been removed from the remaining four off-topic questions.  Future related questions containing no code should be sent to [Database Administrators SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).  Their own [normalization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normalization) tag is well-defined and already has more questions associated with it.

The remaining database-type questions here containing code are still okay.  All the off-topic ones I've found have already been closed.

I'll add [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) after [normalization](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normalization) has been removed from the system.